# Getting error when passing a null value after updating node

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have an issue where I have a call to my Node/Express/Mongo (mongoose)  API, where at one point, if the param I pass is null I get a cast error.

The break point is this call:

```
User.findOne({ _id: ownerId }).then((data) => {
```

If ownerId is 'null' I get the following error:

```
(node:4186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "User"
(node:4186) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

I've recently updated from node 6.9.5 to the latest version of Node.

Not sure how to handle this.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're getting that error because `ownerId` is an empty string, it must me a valid ObjectId , something like this `577fc3002eccc12d154631e1` , so here's what to do :

```
if(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(ownerId)){
    return User.findOne({ _id: ownerId }).then((data) => { ... })
} else{
   return Promise.resolve(null);
}
```